# Read data in JavaScript and store it in the PostgreSQL Database table

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, hex

I am getting a data from device in the HEX format like below:

```
<Buffer 00 cc>
```

I need to read the same in TEXT format and store the value in Database. I am using PostgreSQL as database to store the data.

Below is the error message I am getting while processing it to the Database.

```
error: invalid message format
at Connection.parseE (/var/www/html/project/collection/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:614:13)
at Connection.parseMessage (/var/www/html/project/collection/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:413:19)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/project/collection/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
```

Please let me how to rectify this.

Comment: Have you tried converting the buffer to a string?

Comment: No not yet. if you can help with that how to do it will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with a buffer that contains bytes of text data, you can try to convert the buffer to a string, which you can then pass to your db-call. Consider this simple example:

```
const responseBuffer = await someService.getData();
const contentString = responseBuffer.toString('utf8'); // you need to make sure the encoding is correct
await dbService.query(buildQuery(contentString), ...);
```